# Tic Tac Toe game looping bug

Tags: java

I have my tic tac toe game coded here for my java assignment and everything works great except for one small problem that is when you enter the last move (the ninth turn) the very last 'X' does not show up. Not only is this just annoying as the winning piece is not shown, but it leads to some problems with the tie method not being addressed to properly, thus it showing nothing.

```
/*I have methods for drawing the board, determining a winner, and a loser. This is just the 'main' method containing the bulk of the program */

    public static void main (String[] args)
        {
        //Variable declaration
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        char [] [] Board = new char [3] [3] ;
        String MenuInput ;
        int BoardOutput ;
        int UserSpotChoice ;
        int ComputerSpotChoice = 0;
        int UserTurn = 1 ;
        int Winner = 0 ;
        Board [0] [0] = '-' ;
        Board [0] [1] = '-' ;
        Board [0] [2] = '-' ;
        Board [1] [0] = '-' ;
        Board [1] [1] = '-' ;
        Board [1] [2] = '-' ;
        Board [2] [0] = '-' ;
        Board [2] [1] = '-' ;
        Board [2] [2] = '-' ;

        //Welcome
        System.out.println ("Welcome to Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!") ;
        System.out.println ("") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ; 
        System.out.println ("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'") ;
        System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
        MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;

        do
        {
        if (MenuInput.equals ("Play") || MenuInput.equals ("play")) 
        {
            while (!GameOver) 
            {
            System.out.println ("\f") ;
            System.out.println (" Tic Tac Toe") ;
            BoardOutput = DrawBoard (Board) ;
            System.out.println (" 1 2 3") ;
            System.out.println (" 4 5 6") ;
            System.out.println (" 7 8 9") ;
            System.out.println ("Please enter the number you would like to move your spot to") ;
            UserSpotChoice = kbReader.nextInt () ;

            if (UserSpotChoice == 1) Board [0] [0] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 2) Board [0] [1] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 3) Board [0] [2] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 4) Board [1] [0] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 5) Board [1] [1] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 6) Board [1] [2] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 7) Board [2] [0] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 8) Board [2] [1] = 'X' ;
            if (UserSpotChoice == 9) Board [2] [2] = 'X' ;

            do
            {
                ComputerSpotChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 9 ) + 1 ; 
            }
            while
            (Board [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) / 3] [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) % 3] != '-') ;

            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 1) Board [0] [0] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 2) Board [0] [1] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 3) Board [0] [2] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 4) Board [1] [0] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 5) Board [1] [1] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 6) Board [1] [2] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 7) Board [2] [0] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 8) Board [2] [1] = 'O' ;
            if (ComputerSpotChoice == 9) Board [2] [2] = 'O' ;

            Winner (Board) ;
            Loser (Board) ;
            Tie (Board) ;

            } //While loop
            if (GameOver) System.exit (0) ;
     } //If play

        else if (MenuInput.equals ("Instructions") || MenuInput.equals ("instructions")) 
        {
            System.out.println ("\f") ;
            System.out.println ("You will be playing the game of Tic Tac Toe against the computer.") ;
            System.out.println ("The object of this game is to get three of your own x's or o's in a line.") ;    
            System.out.println ("You take turns placing the x's and o's and whoever gets three in a row first wins.") ;
            System.out.println ("Good Luck!") ;
            System.out.println ("") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
            MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;
        }

        else if (MenuInput.equals ("Exit") || MenuInput.equals ("exit")) 
        {
            System.out.println ("Thank you for using Alex Montague's Tic Tac Toe game!") ;
            System.exit (0) ;
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println ("Sorry, that is not a valid choice.") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to play, type 'Play'") ; 
            System.out.println ("If you wish to read the instructions, type 'Instructions'") ;
            System.out.println ("If you wish to exit, type 'Exit'") ;
            MenuInput = kbReader.next () ;
        }

        } //do while
        while (!MenuInput.equals ("Instructions") || !MenuInput.equals ("instructions") || !MenuInput.equals ("Play") || !MenuInput.equals ("play") || !MenuInput.equals ("Exit") || !MenuInput.equals ("exit")) ;

        } // main method
```

Comment: well, where does `GameOver` ever get assigned a value? I can see two places it's being READ, but never ASSIGNED, let alone get DEFINED in the first place.

Comment: Also, try reading this link about [Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) it is a good pratice on development of java

Comment: When do you actually print out the board?

Comment: Sorry everything is defined above the program. I just wanted to save lines and make it quick here.

Comment: @BitNinja I print the board at the very top of this method, `BoardOutput = DrawBoard (Board) ;`

Comment: If you have many constants and a lot of repetition you get what's called "code smell". It means that your design is not optimal. Use your CPU to do the repetition! It much better and much faster at it. (ok, easy to say, but it may be an interesting exercise to get rid of it after you've got your app going)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Tic Tac Toe Small Loop Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810503/java-tic-tac-toe-small-loop-error)

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
        if (GameOver) System.exit (0) ;
```

is probably the root of the problem. You detect that the game is over and exit your program at that point. It never loops back around to display the current state of the board.

To fix this, you could either:

- display the current board before calling `System.exit`
- decide whether the game is over at a different point in your program, perhaps after printing the current board

Comment: I just commented this line of code and ran the program. Exact same thing happens, which is nothing pops up like it should, (tie method) and the last 'X' does not show as well.

Comment: Well, you've also got a `while (!GameOver)` loop that won't loop after the game is over.

Comment: My teacher suggested I use that to keep the game going. It in theory should run until the game is over, which I think it does just does not go through with the rest of the loop printing the last move and calling to the win, lose or tie methods. I tried using the debugger to help me out but I couldn't make much sense of it there.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is the culprit for not showing the current board.

```
 do
 {
     ComputerSpotChoice = (int) (Math.random() * 9 ) + 1 ; 
 }
 while (Board [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) / 3] [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) % 3] != '-') ;
```

When you enter ninth turn, below condition is always true as it can not find '-'. Goes on infinite loop.

```
while (Board [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) / 3] [(ComputerSpotChoice - 1) % 3] != '-') ;
```

Comment: Ok thank you for pointing out the affected area. Is there a way to fix this? As of my knowledge that is the only way to check if there is a spot open, and if their is generate a new computer spot.

Comment: @xanderman2113, ComputerSpotChoice logic is NOT smart enough to place 'O' so that user can not win. For ex: I entered 1, ComputerSpotChoice  places 'O' in 8th position. (??).  I entered 2, ComputerSpotChoice should place 'O' in 3rd position. Why do you generate random numbers and look if it is '-'. You need to modify the logic better so that user can not win/finds it very difficult to win.